# How to display images in a heredoc in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i wanted to know how i want to know how i would write the image tag and access the string to get the image out of the database. When i refresh my page it only shows the title that i have got out of the database and not the image i want to know how i can get the image out of the database in the heredoc.

In my database i have a string for example Images/pokemon.png

```
 <?php
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo <<<_END
           <h4 class="card-title mt-5"> $row->title</h4>
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('application/' . $row->image)?>" alt=""/>
       _END;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing identifier must not be indented, so it should look like this.

```php
<?php
    foreach ($result as $row) {
       echo <<<_END
           <h4 class="card-title mt-5"> $row->title</h4>
           <img src="<?php echo base_url('application/' . $row->image)?>" alt=""/>
_END;
    }
?>
```

[For reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: thanks but why is my title showing from my database but my image is not working and showing

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that. It's because in heredoc you can embed variables, but not functions. Which means while `$row->image` can be interpreted as a variable, your base_url() function would be treated as literal. Think of heredoc as a long string that you would put in between double quotes.

Comment: How i would go around to doing this